# how to secure AWS Api Gateway and Lambda for Paypal Ipn messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, paypal-ipn

i use AWS Api Gateway and a Lambda function to process Paypal (Ipn) instant notification messages. how can i secure my api gateway to only allow access to the message sent by Paypal which are then passed on to my lambda function. at the moment the api is open to anyone to access and i am afraid of malicious activity triggering the api and lambda function and thus incurring costs on my behalf.

i have secured my other Apis using Cognito and the associated lambda functions using roles and permission policies but don't know how to handle the calls on my ipn api as these will be unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

okay, managed to sort it out. created a whitelist resource policy for the api and included all the ip addresses for the paypal ipn - i was stumped at first because after creating the whitelist, it did not work. only later found out that i had not included the sandbox ip address. after including that address, it worked.

check out paypal documentation for sandbox: [paypal sandbox IP addresses](https://www.paypal.com/pf/smarthelp/article/what-are-the-ip-addresses-for-sandbox-paypal-servers-ts1157)

and live IP addresses: [paypal live IP addresses](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/what-are-the-ip-addresses-for-live-paypal-servers-ts1056)

hope this helps someone